# Binomial distribution problem (lottery chances)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Lottery chances are $\frac{1}{50}$ for every bought ticket. John participates $30$ times, $10$ times he buys $4$ tickets but the other times only $1$. what are his chances at winning at least once?

Does this mean i should evaluate $(1-(1-\frac{4}{50})^{10})(1-(1-\frac{1}{50})^{20})$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost, a slight mistake:

Think about the probability of *not* winning $W^c$:

- probability to *not* win when he buys 4 tickets ($4T^C$)
- probability to *not* win when he buys 1 ticket ($1T^C$)

$$P(W^C) = P(4T^C)P(1T^C) = 1 - \left(1 - \left(\frac{4}{50}\right)^{10}\right)\left (1 - \left(\frac{1}{50}\right)^{20} \right) $$
$$P(4T^c) = 1-P(4T) = 1 - \left(\frac{4}{50}\right)^{10} $$
$$P(1T^c) = 1-P(1T) = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{50}\right)^{20} $$